# $\operatorname{max}(a(x),b(x))=0 \Rightarrow a(x) \leq 0, b(x) \leq 0, a(x)b(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Could you explain to me why we have this equivalence?

This condition is used to transform the obstacle problem $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\operatorname{max}(Lu,\varphi-u)=0\\u(0,\cdot)=\varphi(0,\cdot) 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ Text says that since this problem doesn't admit solutions in $C^2$ we have to use a variational approach to expand the solution space not only to the functions that satisfy the equation $Lu=0$ but also to the functions $f$ that satisfy the inequality $Lu \leq 0$.

Comment: Think about numbers: If $max(a,b)=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$, so $a\cdot b=0$ anycase. Obviously, $a,b\le max(a,b)=0$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Please, see the link at page 19: http://www.dm.unibo.it/~pascucci/web/Ricerca/PDF/american.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that if $\max\{L_r u, \varphi -u\} =0$, both quantities must be $\leq 0$. Also, if the maximum is zero, for each $x$ at least one of them is zero, so $L_r(u) \cdot (\varphi -u) =0$. So, the original problem can be reformulated as
$$
\begin{cases}
L_r u \leq 0, & \textrm{in } S_T\\
\varphi -u \leq 0, & \textrm{in } S_T\\
L_r u (\varphi -u) = 0,  & \textrm{in } S_T
\end{cases}
$$

or, equivalently,
$$
\begin{cases}
L_r u \leq 0, & \textrm{in } S_T\\
u \ge \varphi, & \textrm{in } S_T\\
(\varphi -u)L_r u  = 0,  & \textrm{in } S_T
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Could I ask you another thing? Why if we consider $\tau_0:=\operatorname{Inf}_{(t \in [0,T])}(u=\varphi)$, for the event $(\tau_0 \geq t)$ we have $L_ru=0 \space \mathbb{P}$-$\operatorname{a.s.}$?

Comment: @FrancescoTotti Maybe I am oversimplifying, but it seems that If, for each $x$, $\tau_0$ is the moment when you enter the exercise region, before that you were in the continuation region, where $L_r u = 0$ holds.

Comment: Really thanks for your answers! I think you're right, I tried to open a question on its merits for confirmation.